# Starting Mysql as root

Tags: mysql

I have started mysql on my test server as a root. I have added

```
user=root
```

line in my.cnf
Since I want the test server to upgrade to production server, I will like to comment this line and restart.

Are there any side effects? data loss expected?

Comment: Misleading title. Starting the daemon as root and using the client and authenticate using mysql-root are totally different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first step would be to back up your data directory.

after you've done that, go ahead and make the change. just make sure that you have a user named mysql (or specify a different one explicitly) and that they have appropriate permissions to the data directory.

this is a pretty safe operation to do and should result in no loss of functionality or data. but just in case, you do have the backup!

Comment: There are a few files those show root:root as owner instead of usual mysql:mysql I have two questions...
1) How do I recursively change the ownership to mysql of mysql data directory?
2) Why does certain sock) files refuse to change it's ownership from root?

Comment: i don't know how to change ownership. i'm a windows guy.

Comment: chown -R mysql:mysql /path/to/mysql/root

Answer (score 5):

The 'root' user for MySQL is NOT the same as the root user for logging in to the computer, so there should be no side effects provided you GRANT the appropriate rights to the mysql user on the production server.

That is the user mentioned in

```
$ mysql -u user -p password db_name
```

which *could* share a name with a user logged in to the computer, but doesn't have to.

EDIT: note - an ordinary user can start mysql as root if the correct password is used in
the command above. This won't be the same as *root's* password, if you know what I mean.

If it's not clear you should definitely familiarise yourself with the meaning of 'root' in a MySQL context.

Comment: shantanuo is talking about the user in linux that mysql runs as, not the users in mysql.

Comment: yes, that's why I pointed out that the user in mysql is not the same thing. linux user permissions and mysql grants aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

1. When you start your mysql shell, enter it as the root as

   C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root -p [password if any];
2. If you don't enter any password after '-p' in the command, it will prompt you for one.   Just press enter if you do not have any password (by default) or enter the password if you've set one.
3. for checking whether you have a password or not, got to the `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`

   - you can find the root user credentials.
4. Once you are connected, just check all the databases as SHOW DATABASES; 
   you will get a list of default databases already existing. This will be the final confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

To log in to MySQL as the root user, all I needed to do was:

```
mysql -u root
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16353459)

Comment: hmm perhaps you are right, but it answers the question Title.

Comment: The title summarizes the subject of the post. In this case, it's not even written in the form of a question.

Comment: A sentence fragment like that is assumed by the readers and google to mean "How to start mysql as root".