# RHEL - Mysql errors

Tags: mysql

I am new to Linux, and am using RHEL 6.

I successfully installed mysql and it was running fine.

I used this command to do so:

```
sudo yum install mysql.x86_64 mysql-libs.x86_64 mysql-server.x86_64 mysql-devel.x86_64 sqlite-devel.x86_64
```

I then tried to install some rpm files to get the community workbench GUI and now when I try to start mysql I get all sorts of errors:

```
$ service mysqld start
touch: cannot touch `/var/log/mysqld.log': Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of `/var/log/mysqld.log': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of `/var/log/mysqld.log': Operation not permitted
/sbin/restorecon set context /var/log/mysqld.log->system_u:object_r:mysqld_log_t:s0 failed:'Operation not permitted'
chown: changing ownership of `/var/lib/mysql': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of `/var/lib/mysql': Operation not permitted
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

I tried a yum uninstall and reinstall but same error above. Any help

Comment: you forgot `sudo`. you can't start mysql as a common user - it has to be done as root.

Comment: It looks like a bunch of permission errors. This occurs because you're running a daemon and that [usually] requires root privileges. I'm not really familiar with mysqld but do some more research. It's probably __not__ a good idea to run mysqld with root access. There's probably a way around this.

Comment: @MarcB Is that right? What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1427052/778694)?

Comment: @franklin: that has nothing to do with sudo. mysql isn't running yet, so mysql user accounts don't enter in this AT ALL. what you linked to is logging into the database itself, not **STARTING** the database server.

Comment: @user3437721 `sudo service mysqld start` ?

Comment: get this: MySQL Daemon failed to start.

Comment: anyway to properly uninstall everything and start again?